# Hamilton Circuit?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

For each below, construct a simple, undirected connected graph that has 8 vertices and 12 edges and satisfies the conditions. Say why this is true. If a graph does not exist, explain why it doesn't.

1. The graph has a Hamilton circuit and an Euler circuit
2. The graph as a Hamilton circuit and an Euler path and exactly three of its vertices have degree 2
3. The graph has a Hamilton circuit but does not have an Euler circuit and does not have an Euler path
4. The graph has an Euler circuit but does not have a Hamilton circuit
5. The graph does not have a Hamilton circuit, does not have an Euler circuit, and does not have an Euler path
6. Explain why K2, 3 cannot have a Hamilton cycle.

I have been using methods to try to reduce these cases to degree sequences.  For example, in case two I came up with the degree sequence of 2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4. I am havin serious trouble visualizing these concepts and writing them out correctly. I appreciate any help!

Comment: In the first three problems, the graph has a Hamilton circuit. So start by drawing a Hamilton circuit on $8$ vertices, i.e., the cycle graph $C_8.$ Now you just have to decide where to draw the $4$ additional edges.

Comment: How did you get stuck on #6? (I assume that by "K2, 3" you meant the complete bipartite graph $K_{2,3}?)$

Comment: For 2, vertices of degree 2 are very special with respect to Hamilton and Euler circuits.  By contracting edges you can obtain a smaller graph (possibly non-simple) which is still Hamiltonian and Eulerian.  This new graph will have a predictable number of vertices and edges, and will be fairly well constrained.

Comment: For #1, inscribe a square in an octagon.

Comment: For #2, inscribe a triangle in an octagon, and add a chord which misses the vertices of the triangle.

Comment: For #3, take a regular octagon and draw $4$ diameters.

Comment: For #4, draw a regular hexagon, inscribe an equilateral triangle in the hexagon, then draw another triangle using one vertex of the hexagon and two new vertices.

Comment: For #5, draw a disconnected graph with $8$ vertices and $12$ edges.

Comment: #6: More generally, a Hamiltonian graph with an odd number of vertices is not $2$-colorable. The graph $K_{2,3}$ is $2$-colorable and has $5$ vertices.